# Displaying boolen value in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using the following expression to display either Paid / Unpaid depending on the boolean value of my table field in a *JasperReports* report

```java
Boolean.valueOf($F{PAYMENT_STATUS}.equals(BOOLEAN.TRUE)) ? "Paid" : "Unpaid"
```

yet it is not working and is always giving me unpaid even though the invoices in table are all paid

So can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here and how to show Paid / Unpaid depending on the field boolean value?

Note: I am using *JasperReports Designer 5.2.0*

Comment: What is the type of **PAYMENT_STATUS** field? Is it *java.lang.String* or *java.lang.Boolean*? For boolean field the `$F{PAYMENT_STATUS} ? "Paid" : "Unpaid"` expression works in *JR 5.x*

Answer (score 3):

Take a static text **paid** and **unpaid** there and on the based on static text write in print when expression. for **paid**  $F{PAYMENT_STATUS}==true and for **unpaid** $F{PAYMENT_STATUS} == false. it will worked

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
($F{PAYMENT_STATUS}.equals(Boolean.TRUE.toString())) ? "PAID" : "UNPAID"
```

Comment: I would change it to `Boolean.TRUE.toString().equalsIgnoreCase($F{PAYMENT_STATUS})` just to be in the safe case (avoids nulls and capitalization issues. And the outer brackets are unneeded. +1 anyway.

Comment: $F{PAYMENT_STATUS}.equals(BOOLEAN.TRUE), In terms of Jasper It is a String to Boolean comparison.So either we can do it by String to String or Boolean to Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I think just this expression should also work.I hope field PAYMENT_STATUS is boolean

```
($F{PAYMENT_STATUS}) ? "PAID" : "UNPAID"
```

Thanks
Chandra